# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is not working even if i set fetchSize as 1000. Its fetching one-by-one from oracleDB

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I have set my fetch size as below still its taking long time to fetch records for Oracle DB.

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
         jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(2000);
         npJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

return this.npJdbcTemplate.query(
            GenericQueryCache.getQuery("GET_GSD_MAPPING"), selectParameters,
            new RowMapper<GdsMapping>() {
                @Override
                public GdsMapping mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    return GdsMapping.builder()
                            .Code(rs.getString("CODE_EXCH"))
                            .CodeToIdentifyMarket(rs.getString("CODE_FOR_MARKET"))
                            .Name(rs.getString("NAME"))
                            .FuturesCode(rs.getString("CODE_FC"))
                            .Type(rs.getString("TYPE"))
                            .build();

                }
            });
```

sql query : select * from  GDS_MAPPING

explain plan : 
    Plan hash value: 4000448272

---

### | Id  | Operation         | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                         | 44626 |  1350K|   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |

### |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| GDS_MAPPING | 44626     |  1350K|   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |

Comment: How did you arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: there are 44k records in db.. when i start my application..it takes time to load this table data.. other table's fetchsize are working fine. but for this fetch i get slowness issue..i printed count ++ log in return code above..i can see for this its fetching one by one.. for others fetchsize is quite fast. Dont know why

Comment: You'll have to post the SQL of your query and preferable the [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) of it. Some queries can't use (version dependent) fetch size, e.g. when containing CLOB columns, other queries are *slow even with large fetch size*.

Comment: please find the sql and explain plan in question